# Computer not showing boot process to access bios

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, bios

few days ago my computer really messed but and would not display anything i read a guide online which said to disconnect anything hit the power button a dew time to get rid of any charges then plug in stuff 1 at a time which worked fine only problem now is when my computer restart it does not show the booting screen is usually does like the big blue asus screen which says press del to access Bios it jsut goes straight to win 8.1 login screen.

i cannot find much on this while searching the net only thing i found was that it could be my sli and they suggested trying the hdmi in both cards but neither worked

edit: for a bit more information when i turn my computer on my screen sits on standby and my mouse,keyboard and gameing pad turn their light on and off about 3-4 times then all of a sudden my screen wakes up on the log in screen

Comment: This is called secure boot and is because your BIOS is slightly more complicated by using UEFI. To get to your UEFI (BIOS) you must tell Windows 8 that you want to restart your computer to access the UEFI. Why? So you prove to Windows you have the authority to make such changes to the UEFI. The BIOS (UEFI) could be compromised so it's now very protected and the OS is now more intelligent to know if there is anything wrong with the UEFI data. If UEFI is compromised then dangerous code and things like rootkits can be planted so this is why you can't access it very easily anymore.

Comment: Start Windows 8 -> open charms bar -> click "Settings" -> click "Change computer settings" -> sonewhere there will be "startup options" -> you will find an option to restart to UEFI

Comment: ok thank you i will give it ago i have college at the moment so i will have to try when i get home thank you for the fast response

Edit: ok so doing a quick look around all the guide say go to the boot options screen and go to advanced settings then click UEIF firmware setting but it is not available on mine

Comment: OK another quick update apparently my win 8.1 is not installed with UEIF it is still using the legacy BIOS

Comment: OK, you should still be able to do your BIOS key as normal. PC you say? You could remove the power cable and the BIOS/CMOS battery for about 15 mins -> put the battery back in -> plug power cable back in -> boot PC which should get you to your BIOS...

Comment: yes I should have been like I said I never saw any of them screens where is say" press del to enter BIOS" it just loaded straight to win8.1 login screen but I took your suggestion about removing the cmos and it helped so thank you very much :P

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to see the BIOS message as to what key to press to enter your BIOS then it may help to remove the power cord and the CMOS battery for a number of minutes. This will (in most cases) cause the BIOS to forget any custom or "problematic" settings and revert to its default settings. This should cause the BIOS to believe it has never been used before and you should receive the message tellign you what key to press to enter the BIOS setup.